# Counter variable not working in Asp.net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms, counter, tic-tac-toe

I am working on a school project. My assignment is Tic tac toe web application. I have found some code but it uses a counter and I know that a webform is stateless and I need to use cookies or session. Can't find solution. Thank you! (and my reset button is not working - button10) . I'll need an all time scoreboard after I make this program work

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check who's turn it is
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            Button1.Text = "X";
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            Button1.Text = "O";
            counter--;
        }
        //Disable button so it cannot be changed
        Button1.Enabled = false;

        //Check if anyone won, lose, tie
        check();
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check who's turn it is
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            Button2.Text = "X";
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            Button2.Text = "O";
            counter--;
        }
        //Disable button so it cannot be changed
        Button2.Enabled = false;

        //Check if anyone won, lose, tie
        check();
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check who's turn it is
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            Button3.Text = "X";
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            Button3.Text = "O";
            counter--;
        }
        //Disable button so it cannot be changed
        Button3.Enabled = false;

        //Check if anyone won, lose, tie
        check();
    }

    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check who's turn it is
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            Button4.Text = "X";
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            Button4.Text = "O";
            counter--;
        }
        //Disable button so it cannot be changed
        Button4.Enabled = false;

        //Check if anyone won, lose, tie
        check();
    }

    protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check who's turn it is
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            Button5.Text = "X";
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            Button5.Text = "O";
            counter--;
        }
        //Disable button so it cannot be changed
        Button5.Enabled = false;

        //Check if anyone won, lose, tie
        check();
    }

    protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check who's turn it is
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            Button6.Text = "X";
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            Button6.Text = "O";
            counter--;
        }
        //Disable button so it cannot be changed
        Button6.Enabled = false;

        //Check if anyone won, lose, tie
        check();
    }

    protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check who's turn it is
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            Button7.Text = "X";
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            Button7.Text = "O";
            counter--;
        }
        //Disable button so it cannot be changed
        Button7.Enabled = false;

        //Check if anyone won, lose, tie
        check();
    }

    protected void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check who's turn it is
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            Button8.Text = "X";
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            Button8.Text = "O";
            counter--;
        }
        //Disable button so it cannot be changed
        Button8.Enabled = false;

        //Check if anyone won, lose, tie
        check();
    }

    protected void Button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check who's turn it is
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            Button9.Text = "X";
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            Button9.Text = "O";
            counter--;
        }
        //Disable button so it cannot be changed
        Button9.Enabled = false;

        //Check if anyone won, lose, tie
        check();
    }
    void check()
    {
        //Check if tie
        if (Button1.Text != "" && Button2.Text != "" && Button3.Text != "" &&
            Button4.Text != "" && Button5.Text != "" && Button6.Text != "" &&
            Button7.Text != "" && Button8.Text != "" && Button9.Text != "")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Tied";
        }

        //Check diagonal for X
        if (Button1.Text == "X" && Button5.Text == "X" && Button9.Text == "X")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player X wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Button3.Text == "X" && Button5.Text == "X" && Button7.Text == "X")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player X wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        //Check rows for X
        if (Button1.Text == "X" && Button2.Text == "X" && Button3.Text == "X")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player X wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Button4.Text == "X" && Button5.Text == "X" && Button6.Text == "X")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player X wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Button7.Text == "X" && Button8.Text == "X" && Button9.Text == "X")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player X wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        //Check columns for X
        if (Button1.Text == "X" && Button4.Text == "X" && Button7.Text == "X")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player X wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Button2.Text == "X" && Button5.Text == "X" && Button8.Text == "X")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player X wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Button3.Text == "X" && Button6.Text == "X" && Button9.Text == "X")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player X wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }

        //Check diagonal for O
        if (Button1.Text == "O" && Button5.Text == "O" && Button9.Text == "O")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player O wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Button3.Text == "O" && Button5.Text == "O" && Button7.Text == "O")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player O wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        //Check rows for O
        if (Button1.Text == "O" && Button2.Text == "O" && Button3.Text == "O")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player O wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Button4.Text == "O" && Button5.Text == "O" && Button6.Text == "O")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player O wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Button7.Text == "O" && Button8.Text == "O" && Button9.Text == "O")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player O wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        //Check columns for O
        if (Button1.Text == "O" && Button4.Text == "O" && Button7.Text == "O")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player O wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Button2.Text == "O" && Button5.Text == "O" && Button8.Text == "O")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player O wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Button3.Text == "O" && Button6.Text == "O" && Button9.Text == "O")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Player O wins";
            Button1.Enabled = false;
            Button2.Enabled = false;
            Button3.Enabled = false;
            Button4.Enabled = false;
            Button5.Enabled = false;
            Button6.Enabled = false;
            Button7.Enabled = false;
            Button8.Enabled = false;
            Button9.Enabled = false;
        }

    }

    private void Button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Text = "";
        Button1.Enabled = true;
        Button2.Text = "";
        Button2.Enabled = true;
        Button3.Text = "";
        Button3.Enabled = true;
        Button4.Text = "";
        Button4.Enabled = true;
        Button5.Text = "";
        Button5.Enabled = true;
        Button6.Text = "";
        Button6.Enabled = true;
        Button7.Text = "";
        Button7.Enabled = true;
        Button8.Text = "";
        Button8.Enabled = true;
        Button9.Text = "";
        Button9.Enabled = true;
        textBox1.Text = "";
        counter = 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Try to be specific as to what you're looking to accomplish and what you've tried so far to resolve it.

Comment: you don't need to use cookies or session... instead your "controller" sends the counter var so that the asp code can display it (and store it in markup... in hidden fields or as part of link query vars) ASP.NET provides a "bind" attribute which makes things easier.

Comment: My question is how to make it work? My program doesn't make turns( always binding 'x'), and i guess the problem is in counter